# phongap's error:- Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

when i am trying to build my phonegap app at that time i am getting this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzc;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or     --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.261 secs
```

is there anything missing? what is wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below, solution works for me.

i checked the 'project.properties' file in android's folder.

```
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/app-push.gradle
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v13:23+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2+
cordova.system.library.5=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.14@aar
cordova.gradle.include.2=card.io.cordova.mobilesdk/app-build.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.3=com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk/app-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-  location:10.2+
cordova.system.library.7=com.razorpay:checkout:1.3.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
```

i just removed last two lines because those lines seems duplicated. and it works for me